# How do I add additional lines to stat_summary line and How do I change shapes in ggplot2 geom_dotplot?

Tags: ggplot2

I am making ggplot, geom_dotplot and added lines by 'stat_summary.' Please see the code and plot below. 'stat_summary' will make box to indicate mean, mean-sd, and mean+sd.

```
ToothGrowth$dose <- as.factor(ToothGrowth$dose)
library(ggplot2)
p<-ggplot(ToothGrowth, aes(x=dose, y=len))+ 
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5)+theme_classic()

data_summary <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x)
  ymin <- m-sd(x)
  ymax <- m+sd(x)
  return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
}

p+stat_summary(fun.data=data_summary,geom="crossbar",width=0.5,color="blue")
```

[image]

Then, the final plot I like to make is adding a new vertical line in the middle, and removing old vertical lines outside like below. I made manually this plot from above plot.

[image]

Is there R functions to indicate statistical lines like the 2nd plot. As far as I know, there is no R function that can make the lines like the 2nd plot. If I use 'geom_hline' and 'geom_vline', I could make. But, it is adding lines manually after calculating stats. I like to check if there is R function except 'geom_hline' and 'geom_vline' to make the lines like 2nd plot.

One more question; how can I change the dot shapes in using 'geom_dotplot()'? I tried in ggplot(), but it doesn't work.  I know that I can change the shapes if I use 'geom_point.'  But, 'geom_point(shape=5)+geom_jitter' can't make the stacked dots, so I should use 'geom_dotplot.' I googled to find a way to change shapes in 'geom_dotplot' but no result.

Could you help?
Thank you,

Answer (score 1):

Preferably, you would want to draw the horizontal lines as the `mean`.  You could probably do that using the `ungeviz` package and the `geom_hpline()` function ([documentation here](https://wilkelab.org/ungeviz/reference/geom_hpline.html)).  The package was not available for my version of R and I'm not into updating right now, so the "cheaty" way of doing that would be to use `geom_crossbar`, but just make `ymin=ymax=y`.

Then the rest of the shape would be the general structure of `geom_errorbar`, so just use your `data_summary` function for that.

Finally, for changing `shape=` in `geom_dotplot`... seems like kind of bad news that [it's not a recognized aesthetic](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/geom_dotplot.html).  The best I can do is set `fill=NA`, so you have circles instead of filled dots.

```
data_summary_collapsed <- function(x) {
  m <- mean(x)
  ymin <- m
  ymax <- m
  return(c(y=m,ymin=ymin,ymax=ymax))
}

ggplot(iris, aes(x=Species, y=Sepal.Width)) +
  theme_minimal() +
  geom_dotplot(binaxis='y', stackdir='center', dotsize=0.5, fill=NA) +
  stat_summary(
    geom='crossbar',
    fun.data=data_summary_collapsed,
    width=0.3,
    color='blue'
  ) +
  stat_summary(
    geom='errorbar',
    fun.data=data_summary,
    width=0.2,
    color='blue',
    size=1.2
  )
```

[image]

Comment: I should use geom="errorbar" in stat_summary.  I am sad there is no way to change shapes in geom_dotplot.   Thank you for your help!